# Different encodings in blend files

Tags: python, encoding

In working with blender, we found that blender saves files in different encodings. In the screenshot an example of default empty files created on different machines.

We would like to understand what it depends on, because we use scripts to get information about the file and here on one of these encodings scripts do not work. Very strange situation.

[image: Text]

Comment: What I see highlighted is the version number of Blender that the file was created in. Are other versions of Blender being used on the different machines you mention?

Comment: We tested same versions of blender (3.1), we downloaded it from official site - its portable version. And same version saves in different machines in different encoding. On both machines we use Windows 10.

PS: tested now and its save normal now with header! Lol. But we need convert existing file with wrong encoding in right, Im not sure if it possible.

Comment: Could you just copy whatever you have created from the file with the different encoding  and paste it into a file that has the encoding you want? What is the encoding in the problem file? Don't bother with a screenshot, just paste the information like that you have highlighted above.